# Why I'm getting a huge cost in Stochastic Gradient Descent Implementation?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, stochastic-gradient

I've run into some problems while trying to implement Stochastic Gradient Descent, and basically what is happening is that my cost is growing like crazy and I don't have a clue why.

MSE implementation:

```
def mse(x,y,w,b):
    predictions = x @ w 
    summed = (np.square(y - predictions - b)).mean(0)
    cost = summed / 2 
    return cost
```

Gradients:

```
def grad_w(y,x,w,b,n_samples):
    return -y @ x / n_samples + x.T @ x @ w / n_samples + b * x.mean(0)
def grad_b(y,x,w,b,n_samples):
    return -y.mean(0) + x.mean(0) @ w + b
```

SGD Implementation:

```
def stochastic_gradient_descent(X,y,w,b,learning_rate=0.01,iterations=500,batch_size =100):
    
    length = len(y)
    cost_history = np.zeros(iterations)
    n_batches = int(length/batch_size)
    
    for it in range(iterations):
        cost =0
        indices = np.random.permutation(length)
        X = X[indices]
        y = y[indices]
        for i in range(0,length,batch_size):
            X_i = X[i:i+batch_size]
            y_i = y[i:i+batch_size]

            w -= learning_rate*grad_w(y_i,X_i,w,b,length)
            b -= learning_rate*grad_b(y_i,X_i,w,b,length)
            
            cost = mse(X_i,y_i,w,b)
        cost_history[it]  = cost
        if cost_history[it] <= 0.0052: break
        
    return w, cost_history[:it]
```

Random Variables:

```
w_true = np.array([0.2, 0.5,-0.2])
b_true = -1
first_feature = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
second_feature = np.random.uniform(size=1000)
third_feature = np.random.normal(1,2,1000)
arrays = [first_feature,second_feature,third_feature]
x = np.stack(arrays,axis=1) 
y = x @ w_true + b_true + np.random.normal(0,0.1,1000)
w = np.asarray([0.0,0.0,0.0], dtype='float64')
b = 1.0
```

After running this:

```
theta,cost_history = stochastic_gradient_descent(x,y,w,b)

print('Final cost/MSE:  {:0.3f}'.format(cost_history[-1]))
```

I Get that:

```
Final cost/MSE:  3005958172614261248.000
```

And here is the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbRVR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions:

- your learning rate is too big for the training: changing it to something like 1e-3 should be fine.
- your update part could be slightly modified as follows:

```
def stochastic_gradient_descent(X,y,w,b,learning_rate=0.01,iterations=500,batch_size =100):
    
    length = len(y)
    cost_history = np.zeros(iterations)
    n_batches = int(length/batch_size)
    
    for it in range(iterations):
        cost =0
        indices = np.random.permutation(length)
        X = X[indices]
        y = y[indices]
        for i in range(0,length,batch_size):
            X_i = X[i:i+batch_size]
            y_i = y[i:i+batch_size]

            w -= learning_rate*grad_w(y_i,X_i,w,b,len(X_i)) # the denominator should be the actual batch size
            b -= learning_rate*grad_b(y_i,X_i,w,b,len(X_i))
            
            cost += mse(X_i,y_i,w,b)*len(X_i) # add batch loss
        cost_history[it]  = cost/length # this is a running average of your batch losses, which is statistically more stable
        if cost_history[it] <= 0.0052: break
        
    return w, b, cost_history[:it]
```

The final results:

```
w_true = np.array([0.2, 0.5, -0.2])
b_true = -1
first_feature = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
second_feature = np.random.uniform(size=1000)
third_feature = np.random.normal(1,2,1000)
arrays = [first_feature,second_feature,third_feature]
x = np.stack(arrays,axis=1) 
y = x @ w_true + b_true + np.random.normal(0,0.1,1000)
w = np.asarray([0.0,0.0,0.0], dtype='float64')
b = 0.0
theta,bias,cost_history = stochastic_gradient_descent(x,y,w,b,learning_rate=1e-3,iterations=3000)

print("Final epoch cost/MSE:  {:0.3f}".format(cost_history[-1]))
print("True final cost/MSE: {:0.3f}".format(mse(x,y,theta,bias)))
print(f"Final coefficients:\n{theta,bias}")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey @TQCH and thanks for that. I've come up with a different approach to implement SGD without an inner loop and the results were also pretty sweet.

```
def stochastic_gradient_descent(X,y,w,b,learning_rate=0.35,iterations=3000,batch_size =100):
    
    length = len(y)
    cost_history = np.zeros(iterations)
    n_batches = int(length/batch_size)
    marker = 0
    cost = mse(X,y,w,b)
    print(cost)
    for it in range(iterations):
        cost =0
        indices = np.random.choice(length, batch_size)
        X_i = X[indices]
        y_i = y[indices]

        w -= learning_rate*grad_w(y_i,X_i,w,b)
        b -= learning_rate*grad_b(y_i,X_i,w,b)
            
        cost = mse(X_i,y_i,w,b)
        cost_history[it]  = cost
        if cost_history[it] <= 0.0075 and cost_history[it] > 0.0071: marker = it
        if cost <= 0.0052: break
    print(f'{w}, {b}')
    return w, cost_history, marker, cost
```

```
w = np.asarray([0.0,0.0,0.0], dtype='float64')
b = 1.0
theta,cost_history, marker, cost = stochastic_gradient_descent(x,y,w,b)

print(f'Number of iterations: {marker}')
print('Final cost/MSE:  {:0.3f}'.format(cost))
```

which gave me these results:

> 1.9443112664859845,
> [ 0.19592532  0.31735225 -0.20044424], -0.9059800816290591 
> Number of iterations: 68
> Final cost/MSE:  0.005

But you're right I missed that I was dividing by total length of vector y and not by batch size and forgot to add batch loss!

Thanks for that!